# How do i disable submit button in javascript after deadline

Tags: javascript, forms, button, expired-sessions, deadlines

How do I disable a submit button in JavaScript after the deadline.

Please I need to submit a button to be taken away after the deadline or return an alert that the deadline is gone.

Thanks

```html
<body>
  <h2>Welcome! </h2>
  <p>Please find below your responsibilities for the month</p>

  <div class=t ask> Task 1 </div>
  <p>Please Submit your report in the space below</p>
  <h3 style="color: red"> DEADLINE: 20/04/2020</h3>
  <form>
    <textarea>
    </textarea> <br> <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: can you provide us the code you tried to use for this?

Comment: you need some javascript.  look at setInterval (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) - test condition at each interval. Also check when button is clicked. then remove button. you can remove the button by setting its style to 'display: none;' - but note this only protects the client - if you want to prevent a server operation (because you have a form - im assuming you are submitting it at some point) - you should have similar checks/protection on server, as there is nothing to stop  people writing their own client, and posting to your server/backend

Comment: Please I'm new to this language and this been my first assignment, have tried all i could but didn't get it. Yes I have a JavaScript page which takes my client to this Task page but my problem now is I couldn't do the deadline thing.

Comment: Please use the search function on this site to see if someone has asked a similar question before posting your own. Here is a search with some answers that might help. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+disable+a+submit+button. I understand that it can be difficult to even know what to search for if you are just starting out in programming or in a new language. You will see from that search that all 5 of the top answers have JavaScript in them which may be a clue that you will not be able to do this with just HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `windows.setTimeout` call to trigger an event to hide the submit button. To compute the number of milliseconds into the future this event should happen, you create a `Date` object with the date `4/20/2020` and a second `Date` object with the current date. You then call `getTime()` on both of these objects. This functions is defined as:

```
Returns the numeric value of the specified date as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.
```

The difference between the two values is the number of milliseconds into the future `4/20/2020 12:00:00 AM` occurs and should be the argument for the call to `window.setTimeout`. For the following demo, after this calculation is done, the computed value is overridden with 10,000 ms. for demo purposes:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  let deadline = new Date(2020, 4, 20); // at 12:00 AM
  let now = new Date(); // current date and time
  let milliseconds = deadline.getTime() - now.getTime();
  milliseconds = 10000; // set to 10 seconds for testing purposes
  let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
  if (milliseconds > 0) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      submit.style.display = 'none';
    }, milliseconds);
  }
  else {
    submit.style.display = 'none';
  } 
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Welcome! </h2>
  <p>Please find below your responsibilities for the month</p>

  <div class=t ask> Task 1 </div>
  <p>Please Submit your report in the space below</p>
  <h3 style="color: red"> DEADLINE: 20/04/2020</h3>
  <form>
    <textarea>
    </textarea> <br> <br>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

The comment posted by **developer** should be taken seriously. You should also have a check on the server side to check whether the form was submitted on or after `4/20/2020 12:00:00 AM` using the appropriate time zone. On the client side, we were using the local time zone but the number of milliseconds difference between two dates should be *somewhat* time zone independent, although there could be small differences.

If you want to be precise in calculating the number of milliseconds to expiration, you can use:

```
let deadline = new Date(2020, 4, 20).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
deadline = new Date(deadline);
let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
now = new Date(now);
```

Of course you would use whatever timezone is appropriate for your application. Note that after assigning `deadline = new Date(2020, 4, 20).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});` you end up with a `Date` object that has no `getTime` function and hence the need to construct a new `Date` object from that.